How to use org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec in Redisson for custom object serialization and deserialization?
I am using Redisson in my project to interact with Redis. I want to use org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec for serializing and deserializing my custom objects.
However, when I configure Redisson with this codec, I encounter issues when storing and retrieving data from Redis. Here is my configuration:
file redisson-config.yaml:
singleServerConfig:
  address: "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
  password: null
  connectionMinimumIdleSize: 10
  connectionPoolSize: 64
  idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
  connectTimeout: 10000
  timeout: 3000
  retryAttempts: 3
  retryInterval: 1500
threads: 16
nettyThreads: 32
codec: !<org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec> {}
transportMode: "NIO"

file properties.yaml:
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          use_query_cache: true
          region:
            factory_class: org.redisson.hibernate.RedissonRegionFactory
          redisson:
            config: ./redisson-config.yml
            hibernate_2nd_cat_cache:
              expiration:
                time_to_live: 30000 # millisecond

my Cat class look like this:
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(region = "hibernate_2nd_cat_cache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "cat")
public class Cat implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    public Cat() {
    }

    ...

Now, when running the program, I encounter an this error:
2024-12-07T17:01:51.671+07:00 ERROR 27892 --- [cat-service-demo] [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.redisson.client.RedisException: Unexpected exception while processing command] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property '@class'
at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 263]

The data in Redis is not properly serialized, or I receive error when deserializing it.
So, what should I do to make JsonJacksonCodec work correctly with my custom classes? Do I need additional configuration for Jackson or Redisson for that?
If there is a better approach to handle custom object serialization/deserialization in Redisson, please let me know.
